# attaching property page to CMFCTabCtrl

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am using CMFCTabCtrl in my dialog based application.
I need to add CPropertyPages to each tab or adding controls to each tab page.
I know from microsoft sample we can add control dynamically as follows

```
m_wnd1.Create (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect (0, 0, 0, 0), &m_wndTabConfiguration, 1);
m_wnd1.SetFont (&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);
m_wnd1.SetWindowText (_T("Edit 1"));

m_wnd2.Create (WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect (0, 0, 0, 0), &m_wndTabConfiguration, 2);
m_wnd2.SetFont (&afxGlobalData.fontRegular);
m_wnd2.SetWindowText (_T("Edit 2"));


m_wndTabConfiguration.AddTab (&m_wnd1, _T("One"), 0, FALSE);
m_wndTabConfiguration.AddTab (&m_wnd2, _T("Two"), 1, FALSE);
```

Which is working fine.
But i want to design controls layout statically and show in tab pages.

Any help is heartily welcome...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to add controls on the different tabs in the CMFCTabCtrl? If so, I believe you can create the controls statically via either:

(1) Using the visual editor that comes with visual studio 2010, the visual editor will modify the .rc file of your project (can be found under the Resources filter) accordingly.

or

(2) You can edit the .rc file of your project directly by adding entries for new controls inside your dialog box.

Whichever method you choose, you will have to however place these controls in the correct positions ontop of the tab control! You then map the windows message that is related to a tab change by the user (check MSDN for proper info on the message id etc) and map it to a function in your dialog class (lets say OnTabChange) where you then determine which controls to hide and which to show (control.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) or control.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)) based on which tab is currently active/selected. The mapping is done similiar to how you would capture a button click event etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it will not solve the problem as i need different pages and how to add those pages with control is the issue.